# ListView moving left and right while scrolling

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have following ListView:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ArtistList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5" BorderBrush="#22ffffff" Tapped="ArtistTapped">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="0" Fill="#22ffffff" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="0,10"/>
                    <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="0,10">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding firstAlbumArt}"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="20,10,0,10">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="#ffffffff" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="18"/>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="#aaffffff" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="14">
                            <Run Text="{Binding amountofalbums}"/>
                            <Run Text="album(s)"/>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

When I scroll up and down, the ListView moves slightly right and left, which is very irritating. There are two ways to fix this:

- Removing the ItemContainerStyle
  => items aren't stretched anymore which is necessary
- Adding HorizontalAlignment = left to the ListView
  => again, items aren't stretched anymore...

Is there a way to keep the ListView from jumping left and right while maintaining stretched ListViewItems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the current OS due to virtualisation in the ListView.

The best solution so far that I found is by giving the items in the list an actual width that matches the parent.

It has been discussed on stack overflow already here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361850/listview-in-windows-phone-8-1-wobbles-while-scrolling-though-long-list-xaml/24400075#24400075](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361850/listview-in-windows-phone-8-1-wobbles-while-scrolling-though-long-list-xaml/24400075%2324400075)

Answer (score 0):

Set `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"` in the `ListView`. It should stop the unwanted scrolling behavior.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ArtistList}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
    <!-- rest of xaml code -->
</ListView>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already tried this and it doesn't solve the problem.