# First ListView item doesnt displayed Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

i've got a problem described here [ListView in Windows Phone 8.1 Wobbles while scrolling though long list (XAML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361850/listview-in-windows-phone-8-1-wobbles-while-scrolling-though-long-list-xaml/24400075%2324400075)

So im solve that problem by that link, but when i add to my XAML DataTemplate ListView Grid  `Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Content}"` and after that, 1st item of ListView dosent displayed, its not rendring at all... how can i solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that is caused because you are estabish the itemsource of "Content" in an very earlier event(like LoadState event). It is possible that the ActualWidth is 0.0 when it tries to bind the first item.

So try to assign itemsource in event like page's loaded event to make sure the ActualWidth has a valid value.

Comment: Seems like the ActualWidth is 0.0 then its initialize in public MainPage()... TY