# Why ItemTemplate will make items disappear for ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, data-binding, windows-phone-8.1

I was solving Windows Phone 8.1 ListView wobbling problem and had code like below, however, once I add the ItemTemplate, the contents of the List cannot be seen, I'm wondering why and how to fix the problem.

```
 <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="ListViewEvents"
            Loaded="OnListViewEventsLoaded"
            ItemsSource="{Binding xx}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource xx}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource xx}"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=EventsListGrid}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: the `Grid` does not have any content inside, of course it looks invisible. If you want to see something, try adding some `Background` for the Grid. That's just for testing. You need some other content control inside to show the value from each item.

Comment: @KingKing I thought that it was supposed to show the Items from ItemsSource, the original code without the ItemTemplate don't have the background either, but the items can be shown

Comment: so do you see the shown items? `ListViewItem` is a `ContentControl`, you change the item template without hooking any `Content` with the inner Controls, how could it be shown? BTW, in the default template, it has a `ContentPresenter` - which is what helps showing the Content for you to see.

Comment: @KingKing No, you can't see item from itemsource. I tried to put ItemSource inside the ItemTemplate, but it doesn't work, seems I cannot put it inside the ItemTemplate, do you know the way to modify the code so that I can show the items from the itemsource? Thank you!

Comment: `ItemTemplate` is just for 1 item. I don't understand what you want. The problem here is there is not any item shown. Try searching around on how they create `ItemTemplate` for a `ListView`, you'll get the answer. It's just simple, such as you can add a `<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>` inside the `Grid` to see it works.

Comment: @KingKing What I want is to get items shown in the ListView while at the same time use the ItemTemplate to solve the scroll wobbling effect this is a reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361850/listview-in-windows-phone-8-1-wobbles-while-scrolling-though-long-list-xaml

Answer (score 0):

Your `Width` binding is trying to read the `ActualWidth` property of an element in your XAML named `EventsListGrid`, but there's no such element in the sample code you've provided. As such, the binding engine is unable to set the `Width` property on your grid, most likely setting it to some unset/NaN value. At least I can confirm this when setting up a similar case as the one you provided and inspecting in [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) the `ListViewItem` containers generated for each item in the test collection bound to the `ListView`. Perhaps you want to set the element name to `ListViewEvents` in this case or some other parent element not shown in the example?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I didn't paste all the code, my bad. EventsListGrid is the name of the grid where this ListView is contained. So do you have any advice?